# Reactjs recharts version 2.0.8 is not supporting on IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, frontend, recharts

I am using recharts version 2.0.8 and In chrome and some new browsers work nicely, but IE11 is blocking all the UI but when I reduce the version to 1.8.11, it works fine and charts are loading on IE11.
Is there any workaround for recharts version 2.0.8 to work on IE11?
Also these errors are consoled. - [image]

Error Log -

```
The above error occurred in the <ResizeDetector> component:
    in ResizeDetector (created by ResponsiveContainer)
    in ResponsiveContainer (at donut-chart-widget.tsx:239)
    in div (at donut-chart-widget.tsx:231)
    in DonutChartWidget (at dashboard-widget.tsx:57)
    in section (at dashboard-widget.tsx:126)
    in DashboardWidget (at dashboard.tsx:45)
    in div (at dashboard.tsx:42)
    in div (at dashboard.tsx:41)
    in Dashboard (at app-route.tsx:122)
    in Route (at app-route.tsx:113)
    in PrivateRouteComponent (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at app-route.tsx:258)
    in Switch (at app-route.tsx:232)
    in main (at layout.tsx:38)
    in div (at layout.tsx:29)
    in Layout (at app.tsx:13)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:36)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.tsx:35)
    in Provider (at src/index.tsx:34)
```

"Error-2"

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in DonutChartWidget (at dashboard-widget.tsx:57)
    in section (at dashboard-widget.tsx:126)
    in DashboardWidget (at dashboard.tsx:45)
    in div (at dashboard.tsx:42)
    in div (at dashboard.tsx:41)
    in Dashboard (at app-route.tsx:122)
    in Route (at app-route.tsx:113)
    in PrivateRouteComponent (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at app-route.tsx:258)
    in Switch (at app-route.tsx:232)
    in main (at layout.tsx:38)
    in div (at layout.tsx:29)
    in Layout (at app.tsx:13)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:36)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.tsx:35)
    in Provider (at src/index.tsx:34)
```

Comment: image of errors arent much helpful because we cant copy text to search what that error means.

Comment: knowing what version it supports could be answered by searching in repo's github issue. for this one i have found in the link here https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1994

Comment: DonutChartWidget  file is through you the error Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. you should probably show you useeffect code from that file